# Volume & special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, volume

I modified the problem of Irodov's Problems in General Physics 1.343 as below:
A stationary compound solid consisting of a cone and a hemisphere on its circular base has a taper angle 45 degree and a lateral surface of 4 square metres. What's is the volume of the whole compound object relative to a frame which is moving with (4/5)c velocity along the axis of the cone.

I can easily do the volume for cone but for the hemisphere I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since length contraction occurs only along direction of (relative) motion, while length along other directions remain unaltered, just multiply the volume of stationary object by the factor of contraction, $\gamma\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$, in the units where $c=1$. It doesn't matter what shape the object has.

Comment: Ooops. I made a blunder. I wrote cylinder instead of cone. But I don't see how will your answer work here.

Comment: I assumed you are able to find volume of the object in stationary frame, and wanted to know what it would be as seen from another moving inertial frame.

Comment: Well, can you give me proof of your answer? Besides your gamma factor gets a complex value.

Comment: $c=1$, therefore $v=4/5$ for your problem. As far proof is concerned think of one axis, say X-axis contracting by $\gamma$ factor, so volume reduces by only that factor.

Comment: Is it true for area too? I mean if in the same situation except the cone be replaced by a isosceles triangle, will the area only contract by gamma factor?

Comment: Yes. It is like changing the scale of a graph in one direction. Consider how you would find area of ellipse, which is a scaled circle. Area of circle is $\pi a^2$. Now if you scale all lengths in any one direction by factor $b/a$, you get an ellipse with an area $\pi a^2\times \frac{b}{a}=\pi a b$.